# Read out xml python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a problem with read out the next id from a xml file. My code to readout "aenderungk" is following:

```py
self.header = self.root.find('kopf')
self.header_info = self.header.find('kopfinfo')
self.classes_with_changes = self.header_info.find('aenderungk')
```

The xml file looks like following:

```xml
<vl>
  <kopf>
    <datum>date today</datum>
    <kopfinfo>
      <aenderungk>Hello world</aenderungk>
    </kopfinfo>
  </kopf>
</vl>
```

I'm able to readout elements they are not inside a next item, but not "aenderungk". Maybe somebody can help me

I already tried to use .findall or sth like that, but that changed nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I already found the problem rn lol

Just append a .text to get the text fixed the problem for me:

```py
self.header = self.root.find('kopf')
self.header_info = self.header.find('kopfinfo')
self.classes_with_changes = self.header_info.find('aenderungk').text
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<vl>
  <kopf>
    <datum>date today</datum>
    <kopfinfo>
      <aenderungk>Hello world</aenderungk>
    </kopfinfo>
  </kopf>
</vl>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.find('.//aenderungk').text)
```

output

```
Hello world
```